# Xamarin ("old") Navigation side by side with Shell-Navigation

Tags: android, ios, shell, xamarin.forms, navigation

I am searching for hours and wondering if it is possible to use the old navigation and the shell navigation in one Xamarin APP.

***Background:***

The **reason** for that is, that I am **maintaining an old app with 40+ sites** - with different Navigation through the sites and sometimes complex data passing through them.

***Try to achieve:***

Now I've to **implement some new sites** and just wanted to **put them into the Shell-Navigation**. Those "Shell-Sites" should also be available in the "old navigation".

So yes - I could try to put it all to shell, but don`t have the resources yet AND: never touch a running system...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible.

First, understand that AppShell starts up by doing this in App.xaml.cs:
`MainPage = new AppShell();`

To reach *individual* pages from AppShell, see:
[XF Shell Navigation / Register detail page routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-detail-page-routes).

To navigate away from AppShell into old-style navigation, do either:
`Application.Current.MainPage = new SomePage();`
OR
`Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage();`,
depending on how your old navigation was done.

To return to AppShell, do:
`Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();`

To return to a specific page within AppShell, I'm not sure the exact details. Maybe after setting MainPage to appshell, execute a shell "Route".

CAVEAT: When you think through the above, you'll soon realize that you can't leave the old pages "completely" untouched. You need to decide what user will do to go "back and forth". Then decide how to only include that in the "AppShell" version of the code. But that is no longer an AppShell-related topic. Its a standard c# .net build question, plus making some UI decisions.